# How to use React 18 in codepen?

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I am new to Codepen. I am completing the freecodecamp challenges and they gave me a sample codepen link. I included the CDNs of `React` and `ReactDOM` in the scripts.

When I try to write `import {useState} from 'react'`, it replaces them with skypack imports.
Then when I try to run `createRoot` function, it doesn't recognize it. Then I tried replacing it with the `ReactDOM.Render`, it just doesn't seem to understand the `useState` hook.

Why is this happening? When I make Class components, it works perfectly fine. Is this because of some compatibility issue?

Here is the code -

```
import {useState} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1"

const Clock = () => {
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Hello");
  
  return <h1>Hello</h1>
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, root)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been unable to get it to work, but did find a pen using React 18 in which the scripts were imported in the HTML settings. When using the same CDN links in the JS import area, they were not accepted.  So this works for react 18, and you can use hooks, etc.

HTML:

```
<div id="root"></div>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

JS:

```
function App() {
  return(
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
    )
}

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

Here is a link to a working template in codepen for React 18.
https://codepen.io/AdventureBear/pen/LYqwbwx

I discovered this by serachign codepen for React 18, finding most while importing React 18 were using the React 17 rendering methods (it's backwards compatible).   This one used the HTML scripts, which defeats some of the magic of codepen, but it works!